# Android. How do I set all buttons clickable or unclickable at same time using setClickable?

Tags: android, button, click, clickable

The screen displays four buttons. When a button is pressed, a media player plays a sound. The problem I'm having is implementing setClickable for all buttons at the same time.

Once a button is clicked, I want all buttons to be unclickable until the media player is finished playing the sound associated with the button click. Then I want all buttons to be set back to clickable.

The code runs fine until I enable the setClickable code--the code for buttonOne is disabled in my code sample below. The test phone locks up and tells me the application has stopped and to try again.

Unfortunately, without setClickable, the user could press any button and hear any sound before the first selected sound is finished playing.

Thank you for your time and help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;


public class hipsterdoofus  extends Activity
{
 private int asoundfilenumber;//integer id of sound file to be played

 public ImageButton buttonOne;
 public ImageButton buttonTwo;
 public ImageButton buttonThree;
 public ImageButton buttonFour;


 public void myClickHandler(View v) {



    switch (v.getId())
       {

        case R.id.buttonOne:
         asoundfilenumber=0x7f040000;
         break;

        case R.id.buttonTwo:
         asoundfilenumber=0x7f040001;
         break;

        case R.id.buttonThree:
         asoundfilenumber=0x7f040002;
         break;

        case R.id.buttonFour:
         asoundfilenumber=0x7f040003;
         break;   



        }//closes switch test



    freezeButtonsAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButtons();

  }//closes onClick


  public void freezeButtonsAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButtons()
 {

  **//buttonOne.setClickable( false );//sets buttonOne to unclickable**

  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), asoundfilenumber);
  mp.start();


  mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()//listens for player to finish then releases player
   {

   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpalmost) 
    {
    mpalmost.release();
    }



   });

  **//buttonOne.setClickable( true ); //sets buttonOne to clickable**

 }


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

i think the property you are looking for would be setEnabled (set with boolean)

some code;

```
public void enableDisableButtons(Boolean state){
    buttonOne.setEnabled(state);
    buttonTwo.setEnabled(state);
    buttonThree.setEnabled(state);
    buttonFour.setEnabled(state);
}

public void freezeButtonsAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButtons()
{
    enableDisableButtons(false); // disable buttons

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), asoundfilenumber);
    mp.start();


    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()//listens for player to finish then releases player
    {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpalmost) 
        {
            enableDisableButtons(true); // Re-enable buttons
            mpalmost.release();
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: I used your technique of boolean state method--I did use setClickable inside the method since I was using the myClickHandler method.

Comment: Another problem I had was I left out buttonOne = (ImageButton)findViewById( R.id.buttonOne);in my public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState).  And your placement of the enableDisable call before the media player releases made the code function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable a button use the method setEnabled(false) of the View class